# CSS Animation elastic like ease

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to create animation like similar in this [link](http://www.chooseyouretec.com/en-us/).

I have got following CSS to make something similar from which i toggle the trnasform property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
    
    swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
     $(".main").hide();
      setTimeout(function() {
       $(".main").show();
   }, 500)

  })
    });
```

```css
   html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="main">
    <p class="animated slideInDown">
    Para 2 lorem<br/>ipsum going to<br/><br/>the forward area
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

But the given css does not looks accurately like given in link. Someone please help to choose the library for such css animations.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated with jsfiddle link and added sample code as well. Hope it's fine now

Comment: @AshokShah when you say "create animation like similar in this link"... are you talking about the text animation on the left or the robot animation on the right? I assume the text animation but wanna make sure.

Comment: text animation on the left